# Div array from mysqli database not showing first row

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm kind of a beginner in php but here is my question. I got this var div filled with an array from my database but somehow it doesn't display the first row. Does any of you may have an idea why this could be?

```
$sqlposts = "SELECT * FROM `posts` ";
$result = $conn->query($sqlposts);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$div = array();
$div[] = "<div>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $div[] = "<br>" . "<br>" . "Email: " . $row["email"] . "<br>" .
             "Titel: " . $row["titel"] . " <br> " . "Message: " . 
$row["post"] . 
"<br>" . "<form action='' method='post'>
            <a href='adjust.php?action=delete&id=" . $row['ID'] . "'> 
delete</a>
                <a href='adjust.php?action=aanpassen&id=" . $row['ID'] ."'> 
aanpassen</a>
            </form>
            <br>";
        print_r($row);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
   }


   $div[] = "</div>";
```

Comment: because you already have a `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` in the beginning (line 3), thus skip the first row.

Comment: Yes skip the first call to fetch->assoc and use fetch->array .